# How to split name column into firstName and lastName columns in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, migration

Assume this `User` table in PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "User" (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    email text NOT NULL,
    name text,
);
```

I want to split `name` into `firstName` and `lastName` and update the existing rows accordingly. I understand that I can use the following SQL to return the data as `firstName` and `lastName`:

```
SELECT 
  split_part("name", ' ', 1) AS "firstName", 
  split_part("name", ' ', 2)  AS "lastName"
FROM "User";
```

I guess I now need to use `UPDATE` somehow in order to update the existing rows, but I'm not clear on the exact syntax.

Comment: Don't forget names like Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Carl van der Walt and Jonathan Rhys-Davies.

Comment: Yeah, this is for a demo app and the use case is obv contrived so I'm not worried about real world usage of this one. Thanks for the hint thought!

Comment: Maybe creating a view will do the job well enough instead of modifying the structure of an existing table (what if s/b else depends on it?).  Just add `id` and `email` to the select list of your query and you are there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One straightforward way to do this would be:

```sql
UPDATE "User"
    SET "firstName" =  split_part("name", ' ', 1),
        "lastName" = split_part("name", ' ', 2)
```

(No `WHERE` clause because I'm assuming you want to transform the whole table that way.)

Comment: is that null safe?